# Using apply(dataframe, margin = 1, function(current_row)), how can one pass the current row of the dataframe being operated on to the function?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a function that requires the row number of the dataframe.

```
my_function <- function(row_number){
  old_dataframe[row_number,] <<- old_dataframe[row_number,]*5
}

apply(old_dataframe, margin = 1, my_function())
```

Is there a way to pass the row number which is currently being operated on in the apply() function as the argument to the function which is being applied to the dataframe - in this case my function()?

```
apply(old_dataframe, margin = 1, myfunction(current_row_number))
```

I have not found a topic pertaining to my specific case. I wonder if I am missing the vocabulary to phrase it correctly.

The problem I get from my code is actually this:
"Error in Ops.data.frame(fsrf[2 + band, ], fos[obs_row, ]) : '*' is only defined for data frames of the same size."

However, the two dataframes fsrf[,] and fos[,] are the exact same dimensions. In this case, within the function when operated upon, they both possess 1 row and 2101 variables. They are indeed the same size. But I suspect that the error is coming from the way that the apply() function is applying my_function to the old_dataframe by row.

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Given your function you may not need `apply`! Please provider fuller background of your problem with [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `apply` gives back a vector and not a data frame in this situation, because you use it with `MARGIN = 1`, therefore it applies the function to each row, but it passes the rows as a vector, not as a single-row dataframe.

Modify your code as:

```
old_dataframe <- data.frame(
  A = 1:3,
  B = 4:6,
  C = 7:9
)

my_function <- function(row) {
  return(row * 5)
}

as.data.frame(t(apply(old_dataframe, 1, my_function)))
```

```
 A  B  C
1  5 20 35
2 10 25 40
3 15 30 45
```